# Why useEffect is running two times?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios, use-effect

I am passing data from my backend to frontend using axios but it is executing two times and is showing undefined for the first time but everything works fine on the second time.(I am console logging it to check the values).My question is that why is it executing two times.
This is the front end part below and my axios request is inside useEffect

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './JournalPage.css';
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "../axios.js";
import Logo from './Logo';
// import MenuBookIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MenuBook';
// import ViewWeekIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ViewWeek';
// import ListAltIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ListAlt';
import AccountCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Blog from './Blog';

function JournalPage() {

    let {username} = useParams();
    const [userData, setuserData] = useState("[]");

    useEffect(() =>{
        async function fetchData() {
            const req = await axios.post("/userdata",{username});

            setuserData(req.data);
        }

        fetchData();
    }, []);
    console.log(username);
    console.log(userData);
    // const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    // const dayNames = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    // const dateObj = new Date();
    // const month = monthNames[dateObj.getMonth()];
    // const day = String(dateObj.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    // const weekday = dayNames[dateObj.getDay()];
    // const year = dateObj.getFullYear();
    // const output = month  + '\n'+ day  + '\n' + year + ',' + weekday;
    return (
        <div className="journal">
            {/* <header className="header">
                <h1><span>ð</span>тᴄг<span></span></h1>
            </header> */}
            <header className="header">
                <Logo />
                {/* <h3>{output}</h3> */}
                <h3><AccountCircleIcon className="icon2" fontSize="large"/>{userData.name}</h3>
            </header>
            <div className="navcon">
                {/* <div className="navbardiv">
                    <ul>
                        <li><MenuBookIcon className="icon1"/>My Journal</li>
                        <li><ViewWeekIcon className="icon1"/>Week Planner</li>
                        <li><ListAltIcon className="icon1"/>Daily To Do's</li>
                    </ul>
                </div> */}
                <Navbar id={userData._id}/>
                <div className="content">
                    <Blog blog={userData.blog}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default JournalPage
```

This is the backend route for the same

```js
app.post("/userdata", (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body);
    const id=req.body.username;
    User.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, foundUser){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else{
            console.log(foundUser);
            res.send(foundUser);
        }
    });
});
```

This is what I am getting in my console. Line 4 to 7 is getting repeated. I am not getting anything back on the first go but everything works fine in the second go.
[This is the console ss.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQYxr.png)

This is blog component

```js
import React from 'react';
import "./Blog.css";

function Blog({blog}) {
  console.log(blog);
  return <div className="blog">
      <h1>{blog[0]?.date}</h1>
      <p>{blog[0]?.post}</p>
  </div>;
}

export default Blog;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's when you `console.log` `userData`, then this is expected behaviour as you are logging it *outside* of the effect. This is because on first render, an effect is called last in the life cycle of a component, so the value will be undefined.

Also you should change:

```
const [userData, setuserData] = useState("[]");
```

to:

```
const [userData, setuserData] = useState([]);
```

Otherwise you won't be able to loop over it in the JSX.

Comment: I am passing userdata.blog in the blog component but since the value is undefined I am getting an error which is "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')". blog is an array and here is the code for it

Comment: import React from 'react';
import "./Blog.css";

function Blog({blog}) {
  console.log(blog);
  return <div className="blog">
      <h1>{blog[0].date}</h1>
      <p>{blog[0].post}</p>
      <h1>Post Title</h1>
      <p>Aabra ka Dabra content</p>
  </div>;
}

export default Blog;

Comment: When I am rendering it for the first time then everything works well but when I reload the page then I get that error.
What could be the reason for that?

Comment: @Akshat take a look at my example:https://codesandbox.io/embed/ecstatic-hopper-ykv9x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You're getting `undefined` in `Blog` because on the first render, the data hasn't been passed down to it. Your `Blog` component is waiting to receive the prop `blog`. To get past this, you can just use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), which prevents an error if a value is undefined and essentially lets you defer until it has been found. [Check out your updated sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-monad-93jym?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I am not able to rectify it in my code. Can you please specify what changes do I need to make in my code and where do I need to make that?

Comment: I would imagine you could change `<Blog blog={userData.blog}/>` to `<Blog blog={userData?.blog}/>`. I.e. use optional chaining. Or do the same in the `Blog` component. Again, hard to say without seeing your Blog component in full. If that doesn't work, might be worth updating your code example to include that.

Comment: I am still getting that error after using optional chaining. Anyway, I have added blog component to the question. I am stuck with this issue

Comment: Are you just getting `undefined` in the console, but the UI is working fine? I.e. the data is outputting on the page?

Comment: If I am starting the server for the first time then it is working fine but when I am reloading the page then I am getting the error  and UI also gives a blank page

Comment: Really hard to say without seeing the code. Are you able to make a reproducible version in codesandbox or maybe post a link to the repo?

Comment: After spending over a day I have found the solution to make it work.
Optional chaining has to be used like this with arrays : blog?.[0].date

Comment: Thank you for your guidance man. You have been a huge help. Cheers

Comment: No problem bud! :) Glad you found the issue in the end.